# Unable to solve this issue with the code

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I am having some issues with this question for which i have tried to make 2 solutions.The first one works partially but the second one does not.Here is the question
[Question with which i am having the issue.Has sample input and output](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/implementation/basics-of-implementation/practice-problems/algorithm/illegible-string/)

Here are the 2 codes which i have written

```
number=int(input())
S=input()
w=list(S[:])



w_count=0
other_count=0
v_count=0
vv_count=0

i=0

while(i<(len(w))):
    try:

        if w[i]=='w':
            w_count+=1
        elif w[i]=='v' and w[i+1]=='v':
            vv_count+=1
            i+=1
        else:
            other_count+=1
    except IndexError:
        pass
    i+=1

max_length=w_count*2+other_count+v_count
min_length=0

min_length=w_count+other_count+vv_count
print(min_length,max_length)
```

The other Logic has been implemented with  the help of a for loop for which 3 test cases are passing

```
for value in range(len(w)):
    try:
        if w[value]=='w':
            w_count+=1
        elif w[value]=='v' and w[value+1]=='v':
            vv_count+=1
        else:
            other_count+=1
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If think you can keep it simple with:

```
my_string = "avwvb"
max_len = len(my_string.replace("w", "vv"))
min_len = len(my_string.replace("w", "vv").replace("vv", "w"))
print(max_len, min_len)
```

Or a little faster:

```
my_string = "avwvb"
max_string = my_string.replace("w", "vv")
min_string = max_string.replace("vv", "w")
max_len = len(max_string)
min_len = len(min_string)
print(max_len, min_len)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. It's similar to your `for loop` solution but uses string indexing a bit better.

For the first problem I'm just expanding the string as much as possible changing all `w`s into 2 `v`s.

The second is a bit trickier. I first expand the string using the previous method, and then build a new string where any `vv` combinations can be turned into `w`. I use 2 indexes, `i` for the longer string and `j` for the shorter version of the string, in order to avoid index errors.

```
def longer(s): 
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        x = s[i]
        if x == 'w':
            new_str = s[:i] + 'v' + s[i+1:]
            if (i + 1 >= len(s)):
                new_str = new_str + 'v'
            else:
                new_str = new_str[:i] + 'v' + new_str[i:]
            s = new_str
    return s

def shorter(s): 
    long_str = longer(s)
    short_str = long_str[0]
    j = 1
    for i in range(1,len(long_str)):
        x = long_str[i]
        if x == 'v' and short_str[j-1] == 'v':
            short_str = short_str[:j-1] + 'w'
            j = j -1
        else:
            short_str = short_str + x
        j = j +1
    return short_str

print len(longer("avwvb"))
print len(shorter("avwvb"))
```

Comment: Can i get your email id user3543300??Cause i have developed a different algorithm for the same question but it works little differenty

Comment: I have tried another method but its not working,can someone help out?